# SugarCRM - Database Creation Error

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Good day! I'm trying to install(Typical install - first time users) SugarCRM to my computer and received the error mentioned below.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'sugarcrm' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sugarCRM\SugarCE-Full-6.5.22\include\database\MysqliManager.php on line 278
>   Could not connect to the database. Please refer to sugarcrm.log for details.

I've tried searching for several solutions, but none have really helped my error. Explanation of the error and possibly a solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It appears you did not set the username for your database connection.

Comment: i did! and as sugar suggested, it was only 'admin' :(

Comment: Well, apparently it isn't saved correctly. The MySQL error is pretty clear when it says `Access denied for user ''@'localhost'`, the host is set to localhost, but the user is just an empty string. So it's not set correctly in the config.

Comment: I"m so lost right now, my bad I've been fairly new to db and very on sugar itself. so should I check my sugar configs? or the xampp config itself?

Comment: You should check your sugar configs. On a default xampp install you should be able to login as the user `root`.

Answer (score 0):

Database requirements

```
For MySQL, install version 5.0 or 5.1 to use with Sugar 6.5
For Microsoft SQL Server, download the SQL Server Driver for PHP version 3.0 (as per the instructions on the Microsoft website) and extract the contents to the /ext directory of the PHP installation
```

please follow the below link to proper Installation and please check version also.

[Sugar 6.5 installation guide](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/6.5/CE/Installation_and_Upgrade_Guide/index.html)